# apk is not acting properly

Tags: android, button, apk, back

I have a weird problem with exporting apk. When I run the project on eclipse, it is working correctly. But if I export the apk and install the same phone after deleting old one, it is not the same application. 
The funny part is that when the installing apk is finished I have two options Open and Done when I press Open I can replicate the issue described earlier but when I choose Done and it works ok.
The changes are about back button. My code part is as follows :

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
moveTaskToBack(true);
}
```

This code is not work correctly if i don't run the project on eclipse.

**UPDATE :**

The problem is fixed. I tried this solution and it works for me.

[Android Activity Stack is not working as stated in the docs - last activity in task stack not shown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11006539/android-activity-stack-is-not-working-as-stated-in-the-docs-last-activity-in-t)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: you should not create a new question, instead try to update it. Once it is updated it is already bumped.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead

```
 @Override
        public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
            switch(keyCode)
            {

            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:

                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
```

Comment: Thank you, but it is not a solution for my question. i've tried with onKeyDown method but base problem is about apk.

Comment: @Selin but the title says, it is about back button, is there something that I missed?

Comment: @bluebrain are you reading only title? so, i fixed it

Answer (score 0):

clean project and rebuild it and use that newly created apk,i think it would make your apk works well.this also happens to me and i fix it in this way